# What compiler to choose for Qt MinGW or MSVC in what case?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, mingw, cross-compiling

I am starting with `QT`, using windows 64 bits I have `MinGW` already installed and I don't have `VS`.

- What version of `QT` should I pick (`MSVS` or `MinGW`) and for what purpose?
  Is there some cases where I must choose one over the another?
- I saw that the only `Qt` version for `MinGW` is 32 bits, however `MinGW` supports 64 bits too, why?
- Let say I want to develop a windows app and an android app, should I have to install both Qt's versions [MSVC2015](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-5) and [Qt for android](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-5)?

Comment: I think there's an independent project offering builds of Qt for MinGW 64 bits, try googling for that.

Answer (score 1):

- You'd better install both of them. MinGW version for development and
  MSVC version for release.
- Because guys from Digia, who build Qt
  releases, desided that there's no need in x64 MinGW release. But you
  may get the sources and build it yourself.
- Yes, you need both.

Comment: Using diffent compilers for development and release is a terrible, terrible idea.